# Broken Accessory Link

Tags: accessory

I'm building an accessory based on one I built & use on another site that works without trouble.  For some reason the URL's in my view are getting mangled in this new version.

This

```
<a href="<?=BASE . "&amp;C=addons_accessories&amp;M=process_request&amp;accessory=the_addon&amp;method=the_mthod" ?>">
```

Turns into this

```
http://siteurl.dev/admin.php?/cp/addons_accessories/process_request?accessory=the_addon&method=the_method&S=1234567890
```

Anyone know why that might happen?

Comment: I added an answer, but am curious what's broken about the rewritten link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the clean control panel URLs [introduced in version 2.8](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/cleaner-control-panel-urls). Its purpose is to make CP URLs more legible, and easier for developers to build.

Comment: Any reason it would break my accessory link?  I'm ending up on the CP accessories list page, rather than running the method in my accessory.

Comment: Figured it out, I forgot that the method has to begin with process_.  Thanks for the help Derek.

Comment: My pleasure, Jacob.